# code in C being killed when reading a 250MB file

Tags: c, file, dataset

I am trying to process a 250MB file using a script in C.
The file is basically a dataset and I want to read just some of the columns and (more importantly) break one of them (which is originally a string) into a sequence of characters.

However, even though I have plenty of RAM available, the code is killed by konsole (using KDE Neon) everytime I run it.

The source is available below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

FILE *arquivo;
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
int i = 0;
int j;
int k;
char *vetor[500];
int acertos[45];

FILE *licmat = fopen("licmat.csv", "w");

//creating the header
fprintf(licmat,"CO_CATEGAD,CO_UF_CURSO,ACERTO09,ACERTO10,ACERTO11,ACERTO12,ACERTO13,ACERTO14,ACERTO15,ACERTO16,ACERTO17,ACERTO18,ACERTO19,ACERTO20,ACERTO21,ACERTO22,ACERTO23,ACERTO24,ACERTO25,ACERTO26,ACERTO27,ACERTO28,ACERTO29,ACERTO30,ACERTO31,ACERTO32,ACERTO33,ACERTO34,ACERTO35\n");

if ((arquivo = fopen("MICRODADOS_ENADE_2017.csv", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf ("\nError");
    exit(0);
} 

//reading one line at a time
while (getline(&line, &len, arquivo)) {

    char *ptr = strsep(&line,";");
    j=0;
    //breaking the line into a vector based on ;
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        vetor[j]=ptr;
        j=j+1;
        ptr = strsep(&line,";");
    }

    //filtering based on content
    if (strcmp(vetor[4],"702")==0 && strcmp(vetor[33],"555")==0) {
        //copying some info
        fprintf(licmat,"%s,%s,",vetor[2],vetor[8]);   
        //breaking the string (32) into isolated characters
        for (k=0;k<27;k=k+1) {
            fprintf(licmat,"%c", vetor[32][k]);
            if (k<26) {
                fprintf(licmat,",");
            }
        }
        fprintf(licmat,"\n");

    }

    i=i+1;
}

free(line);
fclose(arquivo);
fclose(licmat);

}
```

The output is perfect up to the point when the script is killed. The output file is just 640KB long and has about 10000 lines only.

What could be the issue?

Comment: I see a few issues with this code : first you are leaking a lot of memory, when you allocate memory, you are responsible of freeing it. Second when you use fix size array (vetor), you never check the bounds nor do you check if the data you read are well set.

Comment: Are you certain your line always has at least 33 and at most 500 columns?

Comment: @Nico238: I'm not so sure about leaking memory. Look at [how `getline()` works](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).

Comment: Now that I see what `strsep()` is doing to `line`, it's even *worse* than a memory leak. It's heap corruption! I think Steve Friedl has the right answer.

Comment: @GemTaylor The dataset is well formed, so I am sure it has at least 33 and at most 500 columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you're mishandling the memory buffer managed by `getline()` - which allocates/reallocates as needed - by the use of `strsep()`, which seems to manipulate that same pointer value.

Once `line` has been updated to reflect some other element on the line, it's no longer pointing to the start of allocated memory, and then *boom* the next time `getline()` needs to do anything with it.

Use a different variable to pass to `strsep()`:

```
while (getline(&line, &len, arquivo) > 0) { // use ">=" if you want blank lines
    char *parseline = line;

    char *ptr = strsep(&parseline,";");
    // do the same thing later
```

The key thing here: you're not allowed to muck with the value of `line` other than to `free()` it at the end (which you do), and you can't let any other routine do it either.

Edit: updated to reflect `getline()` returning <0 on error (h/t to @user3121023)

Comment: The suggestion made by @SteveFriedl is resulting in a Segmentation fault and no output.

Comment: Then this is another bug that was hiding behind the first one. For sure the pointer handling was incorrect.

Did you add the same temporary pointer assignment prior to the second `strsep()` ?

Comment: Correction!
The suggestion made by @SteveFriedl worked like a charm! I just had to make another change on another reference to &line further in the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)

Comment: Oh right, there is more than one `strsep()` call. Gotta change all of 'em!